# How can I make a bar chart in Bokeh were positive/negative values have different colours?

Tags: python, bokeh

In the below simple example code I have a bar chart with pos/neg values, how can I ammend the code to show green/red for pos/neg value bars?

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
    
fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
counts = [-5, 3, 4, -2, -4, 6]
    
p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts",
               toolbar_location=None, tools="")
    
p.vbar(x=fruits, top=counts, width=0.9)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    
show(p)
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to pass color information to the renderer, in your case `vbar`. This can be a single color or a list of colors. If it is a list, this list has to have the same length as the other lists.

The color information can be a RGB value, a supported name of a color or a hex string. See also the [colored example from the docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/basic/bars/colors.html).

#### Minimal Example

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, output_notebook
output_notebook()

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
counts = [-5, 3, 4, -2, -4, 6]
color = ['blue' if x <= 0 else 'red' for x in counts]

p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x=fruits, top=counts, width=0.9, color=color)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
show(p)
```

#### Output

[image: bar plot with different colors for positive and negative values]

Comment: But what about if the data is passed on like this:  df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 5)), columns=list('ABCDF'))
source = ColumnDataSource(df). Then I cannot do color = ['blue' if x <= 0 else 'red' for x in counts] as top is no more a list..

Comment: If you have a DataFrame, than you can play with the pandas logic, convert the DataFrame to a ColumDataSource and pass the new source to the `source` parameter. To get the correct information, pass the column name of the color colum as input to the `color`parameter. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69782969/nodes-with-different-colors-using-bokeh/69785134#69785134).